# css grid children growing past grid bounds

Tags: html, css

I have a grid whose children contain content that should be scrollable. Above and below the grid are a header and footer. Something like the following:

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  Header
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to ensure the grid never grows large enough to overflow the viewport. The footer should always be visible and the viewport should never scroll (the individual card contents should be scrollable instead).

I've set the contents to scroll on overflow:

```
.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But the only way I can seem to get them to scroll is by setting a fixed `height` or `max-height`. I don't want it to be fixed though. I want it to take up only as much space as it can without causing the main viewport to scroll. I've spent a couple of hours now screwing around with max-height trying to get this to work. Below is my fiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/ja94t0m0/39/

As you can see, the footer appears in (almost) the right place - just a bit below where it should be, actually. But the grid items extend well below it. I'm trying to fix both of these problems

Comment: Why try to reinvent the wheel? Just use Bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that by using CSS `flexbox`

> The Flexible Box Module, usually referred to as flexbox, was designed
>   as a one-dimensional layout model, and as a method that could offer
>   space distribution between items in an interface and powerful
>   alignment capabilities. This article gives an outline of the main
>   features of flexbox, which we will be exploring in more detail in the
>   rest of these guides.

As I prefer you to use Autoprefixer CSS

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

The autoprefixer uses data on the popularity of browsers and support for vendor prefixes by browsers. Based on this information, it arranges and deletes the prefixes. It can help you want to get prefixes for: animations, transition, transform, grid, flex, flexbox and others.

**Before using Autoprefixer CSS**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "first second third";
  grid-gap: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 0;
      overflow-y: auto;
}
.first {
  grid-area: first;
}

.second {
  grid-area: second;
}

.third {
  grid-area: third;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
  <p>
  HEADER FIXED HEIGHT
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
  
      <div class="first card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p>FOOTER FIXED HEIGHT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**After using Autoprefixer CSS**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: column;
          flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
          flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: "first second third";
  grid-gap: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: column;
          flex-flow: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
}

.box .row.footer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 40px;
          flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
.card {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: .5em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
      overflow-y: auto;
}
.first {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: first;
}

.second {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: second;
}

.third {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-area: third;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
  <p>
  HEADER FIXED HEIGHT
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
  
      <div class="first card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third card">
      <div>
        Card Header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p>FOOTER FIXED HEIGHT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) but it looks like all that was necessary from your changes to get it to work was `height: 100%` on every element from `html` down to `.grid`, and `overflow-y: auto` on `.card` for some reason (even though it's its child that is scrolling). I updated the fiddle with the minimal css required: https://jsfiddle.net/ja94t0m0/77/

Comment: What do you mean? do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/ja94t0m0/83/  or https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/ja94t0m0/87/

Comment: the fiddle I linked in my previous comment is exactly the way I want it. It was thanks to your answer that I was able to figure it out, but your answer also contained a bit of extra css that wasn't really necessary, so I stripped that out from the fiddle. Thank you :)